# JS Outputting a form value receives 'undefined' in console

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form that when submitted will just output the two values to the console. However, when I run it, only the email field is being displayed and the name field is just showing 'undefined'.

I have created a JSFiddle of what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/hbzxcvjj/1/

**JS:**

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btn-signup"); 

var sendInfo = function(){
console.log(name.value);
console.log(email.value);
}
submitButton.onclick = sendInfo;
```

Comment: Your JS fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It works fine in JSFiddle but not when I view the live site.

Comment: there's seem no problem with your code it as works when I try it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving your variable definitions into the function, this is how it should look:

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btn-signup"); 

var sendInfo = function(){
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
console.log(name.value);
console.log(email.value);
}
submitButton.onclick = sendInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/hbzxcvjj/2/

see the working fiddle

Try with alternate method:

```
submitButton.addEventListener("click", sendInfo);
```